# Asterisk: could not place call through IAX

Tags: freepbx, asterisk

I have some problems in placing calls through IAX... It does not work :)
in the asterisk console I can't see nothing about dialplan enter or
so, IAX debbugging seems to be unuseful...

this is my configuration:

```
enter code here

[612]
type=friend
secret=123456
notransfer=yes
disallow=all
allow=gsm
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
context=from-internal
host=dynamic
requirecalltoken=no
```

I enabled IAX debugging, but I can see only this:

```
Rx-Frame Retry[ No] -- OSeqno: 000 ISeqno: 000 Type: IAX     Subclass: NEW
  Timestamp: 00001ms  SCall: 00004  DCall: 00000 [172.31.199.6:4569]
  VERSION         : 2
  CALLING NUMBER  : 612
  CALLING NAME    : 612
  CALLING PRESNTN : 1
  CALLING TYPEOFN : 0
  CALLING TRANSIT : 0
  FORMAT          : 2
  CAPABILITY      : 1550
  USERNAME        : 612
  CALLED NUMBER   : 330
  DNID            : 330
  ADSICPE         : 0
  CALLTOKEN       : Present
  FW BLOCK DATA   : 16 bytes

Rx-Frame Retry[Yes] -- OSeqno: 000 ISeqno: 000 Type: IAX     Subclass: NEW
  Timestamp: 00001ms  SCall: 00004  DCall: 00000 [172.31.199.6:4569]
  VERSION         : 2
  CALLING NUMBER  : 612
  CALLING NAME    : 612
  CALLING PRESNTN : 1
  CALLING TYPEOFN : 0
  CALLING TRANSIT : 0
  FORMAT          : 2
  CAPABILITY      : 1550
  USERNAME        : 612
  CALLED NUMBER   : 330
  DNID            : 330
  ADSICPE         : 0
  CALLTOKEN       : Present
  FW BLOCK DATA   : 16 bytes

Rx-Frame Retry[Yes] -- OSeqno: 000 ISeqno: 000 Type: IAX     Subclass: NEW
  Timestamp: 00001ms  SCall: 00004  DCall: 00000 [172.31.199.6:4569]
  VERSION         : 2
  CALLING NUMBER  : 612
  CALLING NAME    : 612
  CALLING PRESNTN : 1
  CALLING TYPEOFN : 0
  CALLING TRANSIT : 0
  FORMAT          : 2
  CAPABILITY      : 1550
  USERNAME        : 612
  CALLED NUMBER   : 330
  DNID            : 330
  ADSICPE         : 0
  CALLTOKEN       : Present
  FW BLOCK DATA   : 16 bytes
```

any hint?
I'm using asterisk 1.8.3.2 with freePBX. I Can't change it.
With an older 1.4.21 everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
type=friend?
```

try to use peer and user instead. 
asterisk console:

```
*CLI> iax2 show peers
```

what does it shows?